# Can we clone/edit standard report type in Salesforce?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I want to add a new feild to standard report by default without drag and drop from report builder.
For custome report types,I am able to do this .
How can I achieve this for standard report types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can not Override the standard report type in Salesforce as of now. Please upvote the below ideas

[Override Standard Report Types](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br4YAAS)

[Clone standard report types](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Jcmx)

If you wanted to Clone/Edit the Standard report you can create the Custom Report Type and then use those report type instead of Standard one